# cannot make requests wit urllib3

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

Can anyone provide a working urllib3 example that works? I have tried the example on the website https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/:

```
import urllib3
resp = urllib3.request("GET", "http://httpbin.org/robots.txt")
```

but keep on getting this error (using Python 3.10):

```
AttributeError: module 'urllib3.request' has no attribute 'Request'
```

Comment: You sure you’re not accidentally capitalizing something? Maybe the “r” in “Request”?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use urllib3 to send HTTP requests is slightly different

```
import urllib3

# Create a PoolManager instance
http = urllib3.PoolManager()

# Send a GET request to http://httpbin.org/robots.txt
response = http.request("GET", "http://httpbin.org/robots.txt")


print("Status code:", response.status)
print("Response data:")
print(response.data.decode("utf-8"))  # Decode response data as UTF-8 and print
```

Make sure to install `urllib3` if you haven't already by running `pip install urllib3`.

This code should work without errors and retrieve the `robots.txt` file from `http://httpbin.org/robots.txt`.

Ref: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I wonder why the website is showing the incorrect code there.